# Stop New Tab opening when clicking (Ctrl + Click ) on a link without href detail change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clicking

I want to stop new tab opening when clicking on a link  using javascript ( jQuery ). I found this code

```
 <html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>CTRL+CLICK is disabled </h3>
<a href="https://www.google.co.in">Google</a>
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a').each(function() {
        var href= $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).attr('href','javascript:void(0);');
        $(this).attr('jshref',href);
    });
    $('a').bind('click', function(e) 
    {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();           
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var href= $(this).attr('jshref');
        if ( !e.metaKey && e.ctrlKey )
            e.metaKey = e.ctrlKey;
        if(!e.metaKey)
        {
            location.href= href;
        }
        return false;
})

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code changed `href` detail to `jshref`. But in my case, i can't change href detail. How can I do?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Looks like your issue is confusing.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Sorry for my bad expression. As the title, I want to stop New Tab opening when clicking (Ctrl + Click ) on a link. The above code can do it but other problem occur so I can't use it. Can you show me other ways ?

Comment: What's the other problem?

Comment: ctrl + click is a browser's feature and you should not prevent it

Answer (score 1):

You almost did it, change this

```
$('a').bind('click', function(e) 
{
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();           
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var href= $(this).attr('jshref');
    if ( !e.metaKey && e.ctrlKey )
        e.metaKey = e.ctrlKey;
    if(!e.metaKey)
    {
        location.href= href;
    }
    return false;
});
```

to this

```
$('a').bind('click', function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var href= $(this).attr('jshref');
    if ( !e.metaKey && e.ctrlKey )
        e.metaKey = e.ctrlKey;
    else
        location.href= href;
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L52pcu1s/2/)

**EDIT:** I updated jsfiddle, I just added `e.preventDefault()` and removed `$(this).attr('href','javascript:void(0);')`

Comment: In your case, href detail is changed to 'javascript:void(0);'. Can you do without change href detail like above? thanks.

Comment: When I Ctrl+click, a new window stil be opened.

Comment: @DoThanhTung not for me, what browser you using?

Comment: Sorry, it's OK with chrome but I use IE11. Can you test with IE11? Thanks.

Comment: @DoThanhTung It's strange with IE the binding it's not even triggering, I can't help you right now, I can try when I go home

Answer (score 0):

Try this, when user mouse over won't see javascript:void()

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a').bind('click', function(e) {
    var href= $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href','javascript:void(0);');
    $(this).attr('jshref',href);
    var href= $(this).attr('jshref');
    if ( !e.metaKey && e.ctrlKey )
        e.metaKey = e.ctrlKey;
    if(!e.metaKey)
    {
        location.href= href;
    }
    $(this).attr('href',href);
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#a').bind('click', function(e) {      
        e.preventDefault(); // Stop right click on link
        return false;     
    });
    var control = false;
    $(document).on("keyup keydown", function(e) {
        control = e.ctrlKey;
    });
    $("a").on("click", function(e) {
        var href= $(this).attr('href');     
        if (control && href=='javascript:;' || href == 'javascript:void(0);' || href == 'javascript:void();' || href == '#') {
            return false; // Stop ctrl + click on link
        }else {
            window.open(href, '_blank'); 
        } 
    });
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not valid answers.